# Launch Windows phone 8.1 store application with deep link

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, windows-store-apps, deep-linking, launching-application, uri-scheme

I have integrated custom URI schemes in my windows phone 8.1 runtime app.

I am able to add *Extension* in *Package.appzmanifest* and able to launch app by say `alsdk://hello` link when application is **installed**.

But, When application is **uninstalled** or not installed that link is disabled (checked in inbox mail), So in that case I am not able to go to store to get app installed.

**My question is:** Is there any URI scheme to launch store if app is not installed and launch app directly if it is installed, by using app id or any means.

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: I'm working on a project to implement deeplinking, can you please share some code or reference links?

Comment: Please start with a new question and explanation and what you have done.

Comment: Thanks @vITs for your suggestion. I have done with Deeplinking.